# Jasmine 1.3 to Jasmine 2.x cheat sheet

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, upgrade, jasmine2.0

I am migrating some unit tests from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.x and I was hoping there was a quick reference cheat sheet for some of the simple commands.  Since I have not found one I thought it would be helpful to post what I have so far and others can contribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Jasmine 1.3 -> Jasmine 2.x**

```
  argsForCall[0] -> calls.argsFor(0)
  calls[0].args[1] -> calls.argsFor(0)[1]
  mostRecentCall -> calls.mostRecent()
  reset() -> calls.reset()
  callCount -> calls.count()
  andReturn -> and.returnValue
  andCallFake -> and.callFake
  andCallThrough() -> and.callThrough()
```